# Fresh instal Ubuntu server takes lots of memory

Tags: 18.04, server, 20.04, memory-usage

I just installed Ubuntu Server 18.04.5 on a VM with 4 VCPU and 8 GB RAM. Except for the SSH server, I didn't install anything else.

I noticed the RAM usage on this server is standing around 6.77 GB when I use the `htop`/`free` command.

If I run `free -h`, it shows me 6.6 GB used. (Please look at the screenshot below)

Here is a screenshot of `htop`:

[image: htop screenshot]

Here is a screenshot of `free -h`:

[image: Screenshot of free command]

I noticed for about a minute after I reboot the system, `htop` reports around 150 MB memory usage, but shortly after it jumps to 6+ GB.

So I am thinking there is a service using all the memory?!

I have tried both Ubuntu 18.04.5 and 20.04.1. In both of them memory usage is high.

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

All ideas/suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: This is normal. OS uses RAM for caching if available. What is the real problem?

Comment: Thank you @Pilot6, but it doesn't seems to be the caching. Please look at my screenshots.

Comment: Firstly, please don't post screenshots of text. So what is the real problem. There is a lot of different caching. OSes tend to use all available memory. That is normal.

Comment: Sorry, how should I post the result of free command here? anyway, based  on this [link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/free.1.html) I have very small amount of memory left for applications. doesn't seems right!

Comment: Try to use the applications and ask a question if there are any problems. No I don't see any. There is disk caching, etc. You never expect having a lot of free RAM.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about what `htop` or `top` reports.  Yes, memory is being used up, but if you need to run something, that memory would be released for you.  I think you should run something and see if that application is unable to run before worrying.

Comment: Thank you @Ray, you are probably right. what makes me wonder is that I have the exact same Ubuntu version on Azure VM and it reports 450MB memory usage! so I am wondering what the difference is!

Comment: Ummmm, it is possible the hardware (virtual or otherwise) is slightly different and, thus, different default programs are being installed.  So using the exact same Ubuntu isn't sufficient reason.  Even if it's the same hardware and same Ubuntu, there could still be differences; for example, one server might not have checked for updates recently so it starts up a program to do that.  I think your question is perfectly valid, but unless you are a developer for Ubuntu, trying to find the reason might only cause sleepless nights for you with little to gain... :-)

Comment: Thank you @Ray for your help. I found the culprit and it seems to be a feature in windows Hyper-V Manager called "Dynamic Memory"! anyway thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows Hyper-v for my virtual machines and the culprit seems to be a feature called "Dynamic Memory"!

To make it quick and simple, this feature won't take any memory from the host machine unless requested by the VM.

I am not exactly sure how this feature works behind the scene, but when I turn it on, Linux reports wrong memory usage (which kind of make sense when I think about it).

To solve the issue, I just turn this feature off. Now Ubuntu is reporting less than 200MB memory usage!

Thank you.

Comment: Good to hear you solved your problem!  Thanks for the update!